# Use case for more than two breadboard binding posts?

Tags: breadboard

I understand the use for two binding posts on a breadboard: namely to connect the + and - of a DC power supply. But what it the purpose of breadboards with three binding posts?

In this [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard/providing-power-to-a-breadboard) I read: "Typically, you only need to connect a power and ground wire from the posts to the breadboard. If you need an alternate power source, you can use the third post." But would I not need a third *and fourth* binding post to connect a second power supply?

So how do you make use of just a third binding post?

Comment: if you need +15 V, -15 V, and ground? Really common with op amps and the like.

Comment: signal in or signal out ... i use it to connect an external switch ... that way i do not pull on wires that are connected to the breadboard ... not really an electronics design question though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some components need a positive and negative supply voltage, and also ground, eg OpAmps. This can be achieved with voltage-splitters or just plain old resistors. For basic dc electronics you won't really need dual-supply.
Or if you need for example 15V and 5V you could also use the three points, but thats probably a bit messy.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I would use a single power supply *and converter* to generate different voltages which all share the same ground?

Comment: @Joel Rupp I would recommend against creating dual supply rails using "voltage-splitters or just plain old resistors." Not really sure what  a voltage splitter is and you should almost never use resistors to generate power rails. These dual positive/negative voltages are usually generated by dedicated power supplies or supply ICs.